# Effecient Way To Find If a Key From A List Of Dicts Exists In Within Another List Of Dicts In Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array

As the title says, I have two lists of dictionaries. We'll call them A, which exists within a database, and B, which is live results from a sensor.

A shares Key/Values From B

Example looks like:

```
A = [
    {
        "created_at": "2020-09-19T17:25:29.547354",
        "id": 1,
        "ip_address": "192.168.1.1",
        "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2020-09-19T17:25:29.564472",
        "id": 2,
        "ip_address": "192.168.1.2",
        "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2020-09-19T17:25:29.564472",
        "id": 3,
        "ip_address": "192.168.1.3",
        "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
    }
]

B = [
    {
        'mac_address': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx',
        'ip_address': '192.168.1.1',
        'status': True
    },
    {
        'mac_address': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx',
        'ip_address': '192.168.1.2',
        'status': True
    }
]
```

What's the best way way to find out any missing dictionaries from B compared to A by the Value `ip_address`.

For example, we can tell by looking at the above that the dictionary which contains the ip_address "192.168.1.3" doesn't exist within B. The aim is to try and find a list of values which don't exist between the two, if any.

Appreiciate any help!

Edit:

The expected output is a list like: `["192.168.1.3"]`

Comment: What needs to match? Just the IP address or the mac address as well? And what is your desired output? The IP address, the dictionary found in `A`, something else?

Comment: Good idea, I'll update the post to show expected output

Comment: Syn, I think the efficient way CHRIS way which makes two sets and find the difference. Look my answer for 1000000 iterations of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set.difference`:

```
if_addresses_A = {d['ip_address'] for d in A}
print(if_addresses_A.difference(d['ip_address'] for d in B))
```

Prints:

```
{'192.168.1.3'}
```

---

Or in list form:

```
if_addresses_A = {d['ip_address'] for d in A}
print(list(if_addresses_A.difference(d['ip_address'] for d in B)))
```

Prints:

```
['192.168.1.3']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the `set` of ips for each one:

```py
ips_a = set([k['ip_address'] for k in A])
ips_b = set([k['ip_address'] for k in B])
missing = ips_a - ips_b  # {'192.168.1.3'}
```

Comment: I upvote it since it is efficient than others but if we have something in B and not in A that value also will be in missing

Answer (score 1):

```
set(x["ip_address"] for x in B).difference(set(x["ip_address"] for x in A))
```

BTW, in your example all the ip_addresses from B are also in A, so the resulting difference is emplty (but this is a data problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a nested list comprehension:

```
missing_ips = [item1["ip_address"] for item1 in A if item1["ip_address"] not in [item2["ip_address"] for item2 in B]]
print(missing_ips)

#['192.168.1.3']
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to get the result using the map function of python

```
def get_ip_address(dict):
    return dict['ip_address']


missing_ips =[ ip for ip  in  map(get_ip_address,A) if ip  not in map(get_ip_address,B)]
print(missing_ips)
```

## Methods compared with 100000000 iterations

**CHRIS Method wins the battle**

```
import time
A = [
    {
        "created_at": "2020-09-19T17:25:29.547354",
        "id": 1,
        "ip_address": "192.168.1.1",
        "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2020-09-19T17:25:29.564472",
        "id": 2,
        "ip_address": "192.168.1.2",
        "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2020-09-19T17:25:29.564472",
        "id": 3,
        "ip_address": "192.168.1.3",
        "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
    }
]

B = [
    {
        'mac_address': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx',
        'ip_address': '192.168.1.1',
        'status': True
    },
    {
        'mac_address': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx',
        'ip_address': '192.168.1.2',
        'status': True
    }
]

start_time = time.time()



st = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
    if_addresses_A = {d['ip_address'] for d in A}
    list(if_addresses_A.difference(d['ip_address'] for d in B))

print("--- %s Andresh method takes seconds ---" % (time.time() - st))



st = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
    set(x["ip_address"] for x in B).difference(set(x["ip_address"] for x in A))

print("--- %s Diago method takes seconds ---" % (time.time() - st))



st = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
    [item1["ip_address"] for item1 in A if item1["ip_address"] not in [item2["ip_address"] for item2 in B]]


print("--- %s Yossi method takes seconds ---" % (time.time() - st))



st = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
    ips_a = set([k['ip_address'] for k in A])
    ips_b = set([k['ip_address'] for k in B])
    ips_a - ips_b  # {'192.168.1.3'}

print("--- %s CHRIS method takes seconds ---" % (time.time() - st))


st = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
    def get_ip_address(dict):
        return dict['ip_address']


    [ ip for ip  in  map(get_ip_address,A) if ip  not in map(get_ip_address,B)]

print("--- %s My method takes seconds ---" % (time.time() - st))
```

Output of the code

[image: OUtPUT Image]